# Font appearing bolder on Live site in Google Chrome vs. Local site

Tags: css, sass

I am running a Laravel PHP site and when I run it locally (php artisan serve) on localhost:8000, the font appears as it should in Google Chrome, sleek and thin.  However, when I push the site live, the font appears bolder and thicker.  What could be happening?:

I have css with this for the fonts:

```
@import url("font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900");
```

I have scss with this:

```
@import url("font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900");
```

EDIT:

```
h3 {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
}
main.css:1631
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: inherit;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
main.css:19
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
main.css:60
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
h3 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
Inherited from header.special.container
main.css:1689
header.special {
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    padding-top: 7em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
main.css:19
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from article#main
main.css:19
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from div#page-wrapper
main.css:19
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from body.index
@media screen and (max-width: 1680px)
main.css:2589
body, input, select, textarea {
    font-size: 20pt;
}
main.css:1600
body, input, select, textarea {
    color: #3f4141;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
    line-height: 1.75em;
}
main.css:54
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
main.css:32
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
main.css:19
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from html
main.css:19
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Pseudo ::before element
main.css:60
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
main.css:60
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: What fonts are you setting in the CSS elements? Have you just set these two fonts, or are you setting any others?

Comment: I am just setting Lato

Comment: When you inspect the text (right click > inspect element in Chrome), is there another style overriding your styles?

Comment: No.  I'll add all of that in my question.  One moment.

Comment: I added the CSS you see when selecting the text I'm looking at.  One thing to note, is that the section that reads:     

main.css:1600
    body, input, select, textarea {
        color: #3f4141;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20pt;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0.025em;
        line-height: 1.75em;
    }

is all crossed out.  But it is also crossed out on the local machine, and the font shows up correctly there.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your text style:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

I don't know why it would be different from your local to a live version, but adding this css property will usually make fonts appear thinner, especially on retina displays.